# Swift: how to detect if swipe occurred in subview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

Assume a `UIView`, ParentView, contains a subview, ChildView, and other subviews.

The `UIViewController` attaches a swipe gesture recognizer to ParentView.

Swipes on ChildView trigger this swipe handler.

Inside of ParentView's swipe handler, is there a way to detect if the swipe occurred on ChildView?

Per Josh's answer, here's the attempted code, which does not work:

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {    

@IBOutlet weak var targetView: UIView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initSwipeGestures()
}


fileprivate func initSwipeGestures() {
    let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didViewSwipe))
    let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didViewSwipe))
    let upSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didViewSwipe))
    let downSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didViewSwipe))
    leftSwipe.direction = .left
    rightSwipe.direction = .right
    upSwipe.direction = .up
    downSwipe.direction = .down
    view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(upSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(downSwipe)
}


func didViewSwipe(_ sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = sender.location(in: view)
    let touchedView = view.hitTest(location, with: nil)

    // Ignore swipes if targetView was swiped
    if touchedView == targetView {
        print("YO YO YO")
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UIView` method [`hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest) to get the subview under the gesture's location.

```
func swipe(_ recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
{
    let location = recognizer.location(in: self)
    let touchedView = self.hitTest(location, with: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Should `self` be ParentView or ChildView?

Comment: The parent view; this is in the handler for the swipe gesture.

Comment: Hmmm doesn't seem to work? Updated question so you can see code.